# Parse Cloud Code - "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set."

Tags: javascript, json, swift, parse-platform

I recently created a cloud code function in order to fetch, edit, and save an array of strings named 'Friends'. It has a list of all of the friends that the user has. The function removes a specified user from that list. For some reason, whenever I tried to run it from the swift code, I got the error: JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set. Below is the function and the swift code I'm using. I'm not really sure why this is happening and I'd appreciate it if anybody could help me out.

Cloud code function:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("removeFriend", function(request, response) {
var userObjId = request.params.userObjId;
var currentUser = request.params.currentUser
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo("objectId", userObjId);
query.find({
    success: function(results){
        var friends = results["Friends"]; 

        for(var i in friends){
            if(friends[i]==currentUser){
                array.splice(i,1);
                i--;
                break;
            }
        }
        results["Friends"] = friends;
        results.save(null, {
            useMasterKey: true
        });
        response.success("User successfully removed & saved.");
    },
    error: function(){
        response.error("The user was not successfully removed.");   

    }   
});

});
```

Swift Code:

```
PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "removeFriend", withParameters: ["userObjId": friendObjId, "currentUser": currentUser!], block: { (success, error) in
if error != nil{
    print(error!, "ASDASDASDASDJLASDLASDKNASD")
}else{
    print("Successfully removed user")
 }
})
```

Comment: What is `array` in the line `array.splice(i, 1)`? There's no variable with that name defined anywhere.

Comment: Also don't use `for ... in` for iterating through arrays in JavaScript. Use either a simple `for` loop with an index variable or `.forEach()`, or in this particular case `.filter()`.

Comment: The filter method ended up working. When the save function isn't in the code anymore the response.success gets called. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show me your configuration of the [Parse iOS SDK](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX) @Gabe ?